# How to remove old plot from jupyter notebook cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am using ipywidgets for showing each lab's id and val score. I used the dropdown menu. When you click the lab id, the plot and data frame shows up, dataframe refresh for each customer which is good but, the plot does not remove the old, adding a new plot vertically, my question is that how to remove the old plot from jupyter notebook cell? I am using seaborn plots. I did some research. The only thing is to find the %matplotlib notebook (that cell display(dropdown_team_1)) but, it makes slow and inefficient. You can run the code easily in your jupyter notebook.

My functions are:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lab':['P', 'Q', 'R'], 'val':[20, 40, 30]})
```

```
def plot(weights_df,x1,x2,plot_size):
    sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
    sns.barplot(x=weights_df[x1][:plot_size],y=weights_df[x2][:plot_size])
```

```
def relevance_score(df_en,lab):
    #each person
    df_en = df_en[(df_en['lab'] == lab)]
    #text to list 
    weights_df = df_en.copy()
    
    plot(weights_df,'lab','val',plot_size=13)
    return weights_df
```

```
ALL = 'ALL'
def unique_sorted_values_plus_ALL(array):
    unique = array.unique().tolist()
    unique.sort()
    unique.insert(0, ALL)
    return unique

dropdown_team_1 = widgets.Dropdown(options =  unique_sorted_values_plus_ALL(df.lab))
output_team_1 = widgets.Output()

def dropdown_team_eventhandler_1(change):
    output_team_1.clear_output()
    with output_team_1:
        if (change.new == ALL):
            display(df)
        else:
            print("Person id: ",change.new)
            display(relevance_score(df,change.new))
            result = relevance_score(df,change.new)

dropdown_team_1.observe(dropdown_team_eventhandler_1, names='value')
```

```
display(dropdown_team_1)
```

```
display(output_team_1)
```

Comment: Please can you simplify your code to just what is needed to show the problem so we can copy and paste and run? Just a dummy pandas dataframe and the `observed` function would be fine.

Comment: You are right. I simplified the code. You can run in your environment.